# Incorrect vertical alignment in WebKit of inline elements

Tags: html, css

I have a small definition list that I would like to center on the page both horizontally and vertically in four columns. I have the `html`-element set to `display: table` and the `body` to `display: table-cell;` with `vertical-align: middle;`.

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qVcLE/5/). If you change the `font-size` on line 27 to `4em;` (or anything larger than `1em`), you will see that on Chrome the content jumps to the wrong position, while it was correct before. On IE the font-size does not matter, it stays in the correct position either way.

If you set the `dl` to `display: block`, it works on both browsers as well but I visually need them to be displayed inline.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Chrome. If so, how can I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to your dl. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/qVcLE/6/ . Unfortunately display: inline; etc causes that type of issues.

Comment: Hello marios, that did it! Thank you very much for the fast response!

Comment: Keep on coding and have fun ;-)